# How to address a coworker's undermining behavior that affects my performance?

Tags: colleagues, conflict, bullying

I work as an engineer for a large company in the US and am facing challenges with a co-worker who exhibits offensive behavior towards me. We are part of a three-person core team within a larger group, bearing significant responsibilities.

Despite having 5+ years of experience in the industry, I feel demoralized and underperforming, at least partly due to how this colleague treats me. He has about 10 years of experience himself and has been working on this project for one year more than me.

The issues I've encountered include:

1. In meetings, he consistently fails to provide space for my input, requiring me to interrupt if I wish to contribute. When I do speak up, his reactions such as eye-rolling are disrespectful.
2. He makes unilateral decisions or discusses key matters with our other colleague without including me in the conversation.
3. He makes derogatory jokes about my country of origin; we're both expatriates here. The jokes are not blatantly racist, but after a while this has started to annoy me.

Although he and the other colleague have a greater impact on our project, and their expertise may play a role, I believe this dynamic is hindering my ability to contribute effectively.

Given that confrontation does not come naturally to me due to shyness, I am uncertain how best to proceed. Should I attempt direct communication with him regarding his conduct, or would it be more advisable to bring this matter to our team leader's attention?

I would like to keep a record of his behavior, but I don't think most of it is noticed by others (e.g., the eye rolling). He also jokes about my origins only when we are alone in the office, so nobody witnessed that, and if I reported it, it would be my word against his.

I'm seeking advice on how best to approach this situation while maintaining professionalism and improving our team dynamics.

Comment: He doesn't think much of your competence, do you know why?

Comment: Is he your manager? Who is entitled to make decisions?

Answer (score 6):

#### Either confront them or talk to your boss

Since you seem reluctant to confront directly ("Is there a problem with what I said or do you have something in your eyes?") or talk to your manager.  If you don't stand up for yourself no one else will.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in a three person team, first talk to the third person. Have a friendly talk in a 1:1 situation, ask for the colleagues opinion on the situation, and explain your problem. Maybe your colleague can help you in meeting situations, or keep you in the loop when that unfriendly guy tries to exclude you. Don't frame it as an "I don't like that guy", but more like a "I want to contribute, but I get blocked. Please help".

Next, you need to step up. In your professional future there will always be loud and bossy coworkers, and standing up to them is a core skill you need to learn. Right now.

If someone is being unprofessional, you are perfectly within your rights to point that out. Eye rolling is for pre-schoolers. Call that out. Maybe practise some lines beforehand. Don't lower yourself on his level, but be firm. Unfriendly comments about someones origin is also a red flag. Also practise some retorts to that. You don't need a witty comeback, you just demand him to stop and return to topic. What I found very helpful with bad jokes or inapropriate comments: As them to explain:

**Colleague:** *insert offensive joke here*

**You:** "I don't understand that. Can you explain?"

But:

> In meetings, he consistently fails to provide space for my input, requiring me to interrupt if I wish to contribute.

Please learn to live with that. In a perfect world, a meeting organisator or manager holding a meeting should strive to get everyones opinion, but that's not the norm. Most of the time, the loudest ones talk, and the quiet ones aren't being heard. This is something you need to adapt to.

Answer (score -3):

Yeap, seems like something exactly I faced.

I was let go after sometime afterwards because this guy lobbied against me to the higher ups and screwed me over. He is not your friend and this guy is probably also doing things behind the scenes.

Remember this is a pattern which should be fixed otherwise it will be a problem.

Comment: "this guy is probably also doing things behind the scenes" - I don't see anything in the question that leads to this conclusion.  If we're guessing based on personal experience, I'd say that someone who sounds socially awkward probably isn't campaigning behind your back and is highly unlikely to be successful if he attempts it.

Comment: It does matter if he is being allowed to say all these things in public meetings, a perception is being created overtime.